# figuring out an automatic way to `vskip` with `picnins`

Tags: latex, figure

I am using [picins](https://ctan.org/pkg/picins?lang=en) package to solve the random problems with the `wrapfigures` within an `enumerate` environment. Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{picins}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
    
    A Texas Ti tem alguns intervalos de confiança que fazem parte das análises estatísticas programadas por defeito (p.e. médias e proporções) se bem que outros estão ausentes (p.e. variâncias) mas ...
    
\begin{enumerate}       
    \item IC 95\% para as médias dos tempos de reação de homens e mulheres. Comece por introduzir os dados nas listas da máquina: {L1} para o sexo masculino e {L2} para o sexo feminino: 
    
\begin{enumerate}
    \parpic[right] {\includegraphics[width=0.35\linewidth]{ex1_ICmedias_Ti1}}
    \item Pressione {…} para entrar no menu das estatísticas das {Texas Ti} e selecione a opção {1:Edit} do menu {EDIT}: e pressione {Í}.
    
    \vskip 42pt
    \parpic[right]{ \includegraphics[width=0.35\linewidth]{ex1_ICmedias_Ti2}}   
    
    \item Digite agora os tempos da tabela do exemplo de homens e mulheres, respetivamente nas L1 e L2
    
    \vspace{4\baselineskip}
    \parpic[right]{ \includegraphics[width=0.35\linewidth]{ex1_ICmedias_Ti3}}   
    
    \item Pressione de novo o botão {…} e agora selecione
\end{enumerate} 
    
\end{enumerate} 

\end{document}
```

Here are the images just in case you want to compile the MWE:

[image: image1]
[image: image2]
[image: image3]

And here is what I got thus far:

[image: How to set the red space automatically?]

My Question is: Is there a clever way using \vskip or \vspace to automatically set the red spacing between figures and wrapped text? As of now I using trial and error to figure out how much space I need to add so that the next item and figure get separated from the previous one.... But that is terribly inefficient.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a table to get this layout. Here an example using the `tabularray` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{picins}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{counter}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\begin{document}
    
    A Texas Ti tem alguns intervalos de confiança que fazem parte das análises estatísticas programadas por defeito (p.e. médias e proporções) se bem que outros estão ausentes (p.e. variâncias) mas ...
    
\begin{enumerate}       
    \item IC 95\% para as médias dos tempos de reação de homens e mulheres. Comece por introduzir os dados nas listas da máquina: {L1} para o sexo masculino e {L2} para o sexo feminino: 
    
    \begin{tblr}{
      colspec={@{}l@{}XQ[3cm]@{}},
      cell{1-Z}{1}={appto={\alph{rownum})\space}}
    }
      & Pressione {…} para entrar no menu das estatísticas das {Texas Ti} e selecione a opção {1:Edit} do menu {EDIT}: e pressione {Í}. &
      \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,valign=t]{example-image-duck}\\
      & Digite agora os tempos da tabela do exemplo de homens e mulheres, respetivamente nas L1 e L2 &
      \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,valign=t]{example-image-duck}\\
      & Pressione de novo o botão {…} e agora selecione &
      \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,valign=t]{example-image-duck}\\
    \end{tblr}    
\end{enumerate} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Here the same with page breaks:

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{picins}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{counter}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\begin{document}
    
    A Texas Ti tem alguns intervalos de confiança que fazem parte das análises estatísticas programadas por defeito (p.e. médias e proporções) se bem que outros estão ausentes (p.e. variâncias) mas ...
    
\begin{enumerate}       
    \item IC 95\% para as médias dos tempos de reação de homens e mulheres. Comece por introduzir os dados nas listas da máquina: {L1} para o sexo masculino e {L2} para o sexo feminino: 
    
    \DefTblrTemplate{firsthead,middlehead,lasthead}{default}{}
    \DefTblrTemplate{firstfoot,middlefoot,lastfoot}{default}{}
    
    \begin{longtblr}{
      colspec={@{}l@{}XQ[3cm]@{}},
      cell{1-Z}{1}={appto={\alph{rownum})\space}}
    }
      & Pressione {…} para entrar no menu das estatísticas das {Texas Ti} e selecione a opção {1:Edit} do menu {EDIT}: e pressione {Í}. &
      \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,valign=t]{example-image-duck}\\
      & Digite agora os tempos da tabela do exemplo de homens e mulheres, respetivamente nas L1 e L2 &
      \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,valign=t]{example-image-duck}\\
      & Pressione de novo o botão {…} e agora selecione &
      \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,valign=t]{example-image-duck}\\
      & Pressione {…} para entrar no menu das estatísticas das {Texas Ti} e selecione a opção {1:Edit} do menu {EDIT}: e pressione {Í}. &
      \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,valign=t]{example-image-duck}\\
      & Digite agora os tempos da tabela do exemplo de homens e mulheres, respetivamente nas L1 e L2 &
      \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,valign=t]{example-image-duck}\\
      & Pressione de novo o botão {…} e agora selecione &
      \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,valign=t]{example-image-duck}\\
      & Pressione {…} para entrar no menu das estatísticas das {Texas Ti} e selecione a opção {1:Edit} do menu {EDIT}: e pressione {Í}. &
      \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,valign=t]{example-image-duck}\\
      & Digite agora os tempos da tabela do exemplo de homens e mulheres, respetivamente nas L1 e L2 &
      \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,valign=t]{example-image-duck}\\
      & Pressione de novo o botão {…} e agora selecione &
      \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,valign=t]{example-image-duck}\\
      & Pressione {…} para entrar no menu das estatísticas das {Texas Ti} e selecione a opção {1:Edit} do menu {EDIT}: e pressione {Í}. &
      \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,valign=t]{example-image-duck}\\
      & Digite agora os tempos da tabela do exemplo de homens e mulheres, respetivamente nas L1 e L2 &
      \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,valign=t]{example-image-duck}\\
      & Pressione de novo o botão {…} e agora selecione &
      \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,valign=t]{example-image-duck}\\
      & Pressione {…} para entrar no menu das estatísticas das {Texas Ti} e selecione a opção {1:Edit} do menu {EDIT}: e pressione {Í}. &
      \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,valign=t]{example-image-duck}\\
      & Digite agora os tempos da tabela do exemplo de homens e mulheres, respetivamente nas L1 e L2 &
      \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,valign=t]{example-image-duck}\\
      & Pressione de novo o botão {…} e agora selecione &
      \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,valign=t]{example-image-duck}\\
      & Pressione {…} para entrar no menu das estatísticas das {Texas Ti} e selecione a opção {1:Edit} do menu {EDIT}: e pressione {Í}. &
      \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,valign=t]{example-image-duck}\\
      & Digite agora os tempos da tabela do exemplo de homens e mulheres, respetivamente nas L1 e L2 &
      \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,valign=t]{example-image-duck}\\
      & Pressione de novo o botão {…} e agora selecione &
      \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,valign=t]{example-image-duck}\\
    \end{longtblr}    
\end{enumerate} 

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz!... I got it to work... but the tblr does not break across pages. Is there a way to make it breank? maybe with longtable?

Comment: @JPMD The `longtblr` environment can break across packages

Comment: yes it can, but I am struggling with it... Now I need to remove the `contfoot-text`` :-). Thanks a lot samcarter, you got me in the right path!
\DefTblrTemplate{contfoot-text}{default}{}
\DefTblrTemplate{conthead-text}{default}{}
\DefTblrTemplate{caption}{default}{}
\DefTblrTemplate{conthead}{default}{}
\DefTblrTemplate{capcont}{default}{}

Comment: @JPMD I updated my answer to show a solution with pagebreaks

Comment: adding the file to a larger document producwe erroneous pagebreaks :-(

Comment: the package xtab has better control over linebreals, using the  \xentrystretch{-0.6}. I am switching to \begin{xtabular]... \end{xtabular}. Thanks to Peter Wilson, Herries Press for making xtab!